# Best practice to keep method visibility with Spring @Controller stereotype

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, coding-style, pmd

My project at current job use **private** access modifier for methods of MVC controllers:

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    private ModelAndView helloWorld() {
```

I have integrated PMD and his report has a lot of:

```
/src/main/java/com/web/controller/SignalController.java:91: Avoid unused private
                                            methods such as 'handleNewRequest()'.
```

So instead of disabling useful PMD rule I think to change controller's methods visibility to **public**.

Are there any reasons to keep controller's methods **private**?

Comment: Not only is it pointless (at least in my opinion), but it also means that they're not being tested. Part of the value of Spring (and it's ability to return data the way that it does) is that you can very easily unit test your controllers without having to worry about raw HTML parsing (or other ugly tactics).

Comment: Agree with Colin. Appears to be no value in keeping your controller methods private. In general testing private methods requires reflection and is a pain. If you have to test private methods you can use something like JMockit's [Deencapsulation](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/javadoc/mockit/Deencapsulation.html) util.

Comment: We use **SpringJUnit4ClassRunner** with **HandlerAdapter** and **MockHttpServletRequest** + **MockHttpServletResponse**. So keeping method private doesn't make testing impossible ))

Comment: You're shooting yourself in the foot by making it private: 1. it's seen as unused by PMD and the IDEs (and, transitively, all the other private methods it calls, too). So you or a colleague might mistakenly remove private methods that are actually used. 2. It makes it much harder to **unit**-test them. 3. It's unconventional, making your code look weird to experiences Spring developers. 4. They're logically public,since they're called by code outside of the class and package.

Comment: @JBNizet Do you mind to make comment as answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're shooting yourself in the foot by making it private:

1. it's seen as unused by PMD and the IDEs (and, transitively, all the other private methods it calls, too). So you or a collegue might mistakenly remove private methods that are actually used.
2. It makes it much harder to **unit**-test them.
3. It's unconventional, making your code look weird to experienced Spring developers.
4. They're logically public, since they're called by code outside of the class and package.

Comment: I have seen the auto-wired dependencies are `null` inside a private @RequestMapping method, and when I made it public the dependencies were available.

Comment: 1. They would be seen as unused in an IDE regardless, since Spring executes them with reflection.
2. This is true, though personally I would use an Integration Test, not a Unit Test, to test a RestController, where again, they are executed with reflection.
3. Agreed
4. Agreed

FYI, I came here to see about the downside of making them package-access, to discourage other devs from hard-coding direct calls to them.